# Firestore real-time listener update frequency: too expensive?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firebase Firestore (and real-time databases altogether) and I've been experimenting with the real-time features that it provides via the `onSnapShot` function and I'm wondering what is considered "expensive" in terms of the frequency and number of writes I make to the database.

I'm currently working on a task management app for teams (sort of like Asana), and I want the creation and updating of tasks to update in real-time on all clients in the group, and it's the editing of items where I start to wonder about the expense.

Here is a simplified version of my current setup:

**App.js**:

```
const App = () => {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
     const todoQuery = query(collection(db, "todos"));
     const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(todoQuery, (querySnapshot) => {
        const todos = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        setTodoList(todos);
   });
   
   return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);



  return (
    <div className="App">
        {todoList.map((item) => (
          <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**TodoItem.js**:

```
const TodoItem = ({ item }) => {

   const editItem = async ({ target: { value } }) => {
      const updatedItem = {
        ...item,
        text: value,
      };

      // is this expensive?
      const docToUpdate = doc(db, "todos", item.id);
      await setDoc(docToUpdate, updatedItem);
   };

   const toggleCompletion = async () => {

      const updatedItem = {
        ...item,
        isComplete: !item.isComplete,
      };

      const docToUpdate = doc(db, "todos", item.id);
      await setDoc(docToUpdate, updatedItem);
   };

   return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={item.isComplete}
          onChange={toggleCompletion}
        />
        {item.todoId}:
        <input value={item.text} onChange={editItem} />
      </div>
   );
}
```

The area of concern is in the `editItem` function change handler that is called each time a keystroke is made in the `<input />`. This function writes to the database on every keystroke, which results in real-time updates on other clients due to the `onSnapshot` listener, however, I feel that this is not a good idea. But, as mentioned before, I am new to Firestore and am not sure what exactly classifies expensive operations.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "expensive" is really a subjective term here. Can you edit to show what number is increasing at what rate, and what you expect it to do instead?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the current behavior is as desired; task edits successfully update in other connected clients every keystroke. As for the increase rate, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that. The database is being written to with each character change in the task text, which results in ```onSnapshot``` to be fired in other clients at the same rate, so I guess the rate depends on the speed that the editor types.

Comment: If you don't want to broadcast every character, then you shouldn't write each character to the database. For example, have a look at [how to debounce in JavaScript](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+how+to+debounce+in+JavaScript%3F).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I see, you're totally right! Seems a lot more like a JavaScript problem than a Firebase one. Thank you!